# Como criar listeners para vários elementos em um loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop

Meu código está muito repetitivo, quero usar um loop para resolver isso, mas não sei como fazer.

````
$(document).ready(function()
{

  //Atribui aos campos de código do Pokemon a função que carrega os dados dos pokemons:
  $("#pok11").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok11");
  });
  $("#pok12").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok12");
  });
  $("#pok13").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok13");
  });
  $("#pok14").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok14");
  });
  $("#pok15").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok15");
  });
  $("#pok16").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok16");
  });
  $("#pok21").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok21");
  });
  $("#pok22").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok22");
  });
  $("#pok23").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok23");
  });
  $("#pok24").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok24");
  });
  $("#pok25").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok25");
  });
  $("#pok26").focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon("pok26");
  });
  ```
````

Comment: Poderia inserir o `Html` referente a dúvida tbm?

Comment: Como vc não informou o HTML, segue um "chute": https://jsfiddle.net/eckqrxoy/3/ - a ideia é usar event delegation, como já dito em um comentário lá embaixo: em vez de ter vários `focusout`, coloque apenas um no elemento pai, que já servirá para os filhos também - claro que aí depende de como está o HTML, mas como não foi informado, fica a sugestão

Comment: @AugustoVasques Como era só pra dar uma ideia geral (e não uma solução - caso contrário eu teria respondido), nem liguei pra esses detalhes. Mas sim, dependendo das ações do usuário, pode entrar em loop (e estou com preguiça de arrumar) :-)

Comment: Se alguma resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se preferir uma das outras respostas, pode marcá-la como correta/aceita, mas apenas uma resposta pode ser marcada dessa forma. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar. Também veja [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)

Comment: Quanto a sua nova pergunta. Crie uma nova pergunta pressionando o botão [Faça uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) situado no canto direito superior da página. Para conhecer um mais sobre o funcionamento do site veja a [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade).

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa simples é em HTML conceber um [atributo classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) comum aos elementos que deseja adicionar os listeners e em Javascript(JQuery) adicionar o listener a todos elementos que contenha essa classe.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Todos os elementos cujo o atributo classe contenha a classe pokload adiciona o listener.
  $(".pokload").focusout(function() {
    carregarPokemon(this.id);
  });
});
//Implementação hipotética da função carregarPokemon()
function carregarPokemon(n) {
  console.log(n);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="pok11" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok12" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok13" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok14" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok15" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok16" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok21" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok22" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok23" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok24" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok25" class="pokload"><br>
<input id="pok26" class="pokload"><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

A questão aqui não "criar um loop em jQuery", mas "criar um loop em JavaScript". O fato de usar jQuery não faz com que tenha uma implementação específica, apenas usando a estrutura do Javascript é o suficiente.

Coisas básicas para refatorar código duplicado:

**Isole o que é comum:**

```
$("#pokXX").focusout(function(){
  carregarPokemon("pokXX");
});
```

**Encontre uma forma de manipular o que é variável (XX), seja num método, laço, etc:**

Aqui tem os valores de 11 a 26 (XX), então pode fazer um laço com for:

```
for(var cont=11; cont<=25; cont++) {
  var idPok = "pok" + cont;
  
  $("#"+idPok).focusout(function(){
     carregarPokemon(idPok);
  });
}
```

**EDIT**: conforme bem observado pelo @rafael-tavares, existem "buracos" na sequência, ou seja, números que não tem um elemento, e ao fazer o laço com valores entre 11 e 26, vai tentar associar um evento a um elemento inexistente (na prática, dará erro ao retornar um nulo por não encontrar o elemento). Nesse caso, uma opção é um criar um array com a lista de ids válidos, e aproveitar a estrutura do `for` usando esse array:

```
let poks = ['pok11', 'pok12', 'pok13', 'pok14', 'pok15', 'pok16', 'pok21', 'pok22','pok23','pok24','pok25','pok26'];

for(var i=0; i<poks.length; i++) {
  $("#"+poks[i]).focusout(function(){
    carregarPokemon(poks[i]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Seu `for` tentará criar listeners para elementos que não existem (ao menos, que não estão na pergunta). Acho que uma solução melhor para esse caso seria criar um array: `['pok11', 'pok12', 'pok13', 'pok14', 'pok15', 'pok16', 'pok21'...]`

Comment: sim @RafaelTavares bem notado, eu coloquei um exemplo mais "genérico", mas não tinha percebido isso, vou editar a pergunta com essa sugestão obrigado :)

Comment: Melhor que vários _listeners_ é criar somente um _listener_, anexado no mínimo no parente comum a todos os elementos, e fazer uso de _event delegation_.

Comment: tem razão @LuizFelipe, e podem ter várias formas de resolver, mas eu tentei fazer uma abordagem mais didática que ao mesmo respondesse o que tem na pergunta *"quero usar um loop para resolver isso"*

Answer (score 0):

Deixo mais uma alternativa de como pode ser feito, dependendo do seu `HTML`, que não foi postado. Vc pode se basear em um **elemento pai** e através do método [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) encontrar o **elemento filho** `desfocado`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pai').find('input').focusout(function() {
    carregarPokemon($(this).attr('id'));
  });
})

function carregarPokemon(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pai">
  <input id="pok11"><br>
  <input id="pok12"><br>
  <input id="pok13"><br>
  <input id="pok14"><br>
  <input id="pok15"><br>
  <input id="pok16"><br>
  <input id="pok21"><br>
  <input id="pok22"><br>
  <input id="pok23"><br>
  <input id="pok24"><br>
  <input id="pok25"><br>
  <input id="pok26"><br>
</div>
```

Desta maneira consegue controlar melhor o que quer pegar, inclusve filtrar o que precisa pegar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pai').find('input').focusout(function() {
    if($(this).attr('name') === 'teste') carregarPokemon($(this).attr('id'));
    if($(this).attr('class') === 'pokload') carregarPokemon($(this).attr('id'));
  });
})

function carregarPokemon(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pai">
  <input id="pok11" name="teste"><br>
  <input id="pok12"><br>
  <input id="pok13"><br>
  <input id="pok14"><br>
  <input id="pok15" class="pokload"><br>
  <input id="pok16"><br>
  <input id="pok21"><br>
  <input id="pok22"><br>
  <input id="pok23"><br>
  <input id="pok24"><br>
  <input id="pok25"><br>
  <input id="pok26"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Como você colocou os elementos `<input>` dentro dum container não precisa usar o `find()`. basta apensar o `focusout` no container assim: `$('#pai').focusout(function() {.... ....});`

Comment: @AugustoVasques Não entendi o que quis dizer, como assim retirar o **`find()`** por causa de um container?? Não entendi sua colocação!

Comment: Só esclarecer que [não fui eu quem negativou](https://imgur.com/a/4rVYzWa). Quando atribui o evento `focusout` a um container esse evento é disparado quando um elemento aninhado perde o foco.  `$('#pai').focusout(function(e) {carregarPokemon(e.target.id);});`. Veja [Delegação de eventos(tópico logo acima do destino do link )](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#conclus%C3%A3o)

Comment: Certo, mas, o **`find('input')`** é de propósito mesmo. Como em todas as respostas a minha tbm foi baseada em um `HTML` inexistente e sugestivo, e se, por exemplo dentro do cointaner houver outros elementos que podem tanto receber foco como perde-lo (button, textarea, select, etc..)?  Do jeito que mostrou, logo esses campos tbm executariam a função desnecessariamente! Quanto a pontuação, eu não ligo pra isso não ;)